# Что это за язык программирования

Tags: bash

Мне нужно узнать что это за язык программирования. Хочу изучить скрипт, но не могу разобраться что это за ЯП?

```sh
if [[ "$(locale | grep LANG | grep -o ru)" == "ru" ]]; then
    LANGUAGE="Russian"
else
    LANGUAGE="English"
fi

source $(dirname $0)/lang/main.sh

function selectInterface {
    clear
    COUNTER=0

    while read -r line ; do
        DEVS[$COUNTER]=$line
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
    done < <(sudo iw dev | grep -E "Interface " | sed "s/   Interface //")


    if [[ ${#DEVS[@]} == 0 ]]; then
        echo -e ${Lang[Strings1]}
        exit        
    fi

    if [[ ${#DEVS[@]} == 1 ]]; then
        echo -e ${Lang[Strings2]}
        IFACE=${DEVS[0]}
    fi

    if [[ ${#DEVS[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
        COUNTER=0
        echo ${Lang[Strings3]}
        for i in "${DEVS[@]}";
        do
            echo "$((COUNTER+1)). ${DEVS[COUNTER]}  `sudo airmon-ng | grep ${DEVS[COUNTER]} | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print " // " $0}'`"
            COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
        done
        read -p "${Lang[Strings4]} " INTNUM 
        IFACE=${DEVS[$((INTNUM-1))]}        
    fi

    if [ $REPLY -eq 71 ]; then
        echo "=============================================================="
    else
        REPLY=""
        showMainMenu
    fi
}
```

Comment: Это так язык прогроммирования нызвается?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, конкретно этот — `bash` с кучей bashism'ов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это скрипт, написанный на [Bash/Shell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash).

[Bash](https://linuxgeeks.ru/bash-1.htm) - это командная оболочка, интерпретатор, используемый в Unix системах для взаимодействия с ОС.